# How to find the count of and total sizes of multiple files in directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, redhat

I have a directory, inside it multiple directories which contains many type of files.

I want to find `*.jpg` files then to get the count and total size of all individual one.

I know I have to use `find wc -l` and `du -ch`  but I don't know how to combine them in a single  script or in a single command.

`find . -type f  name "*.jpg" -exec` - not sure how to connect all the three

Comment: Create an array of all those files, then loop over the array and sum up the information you need. Of course this does not work with `sh`, but it works with `bash`.

Answer (score 6):

Supposing your starting folder is `.`, this will give you all files and the total size:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec du -ch {} +
```

The `+` at the end executes `du -ch` on all files at once - rather than per file, allowing you the get the frand total.
If you want to know only the total, add `| tail -n 1` at the end.

Fair warning: this in fact executes

```
du -ch file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Which may break for very many files.
To check how many:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

That's what is configured on my system.

This doesn't give you the number of files though. You'll need to catch the output of `find` and use it twice.

The last line is the total, so we'll use all but the last line to get the number of files, and the last one for the total:

```
OUT=$(find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec du -ch {} +)
N=$(echo "$OUT" | head -n -1 | wc -l)
SIZE=$(echo "$OUT" | tail -n 1)
echo "Number of files: $N"
echo $SIZE
```

Which for me gives:

```
Number of files: 143
584K    total
```